# Multiple filter using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to combine the results of a list and a linq query to get the common records. I have a list named VehicleList which I am getting with the below linq query:

```
string vehicleId = "blahblah";
var vehicleList= await VehicleDetailsWhere(r => r.VehicleId == vehicleId)
    .ToListAsync();
```

vehicleList will contain objects of VehcileName, ReportId, VehicleColor, VIN etc.

I have other query as below:

```
var filterList = await (
    from vehicleFilter in VehicleFilters
    join report in VehicleReports
        on vehicleReport.ReportId equals report.Report
    select vehicleFilter).ListAsync().
```

The common parameter between the three entities is the `reportId`.

EDIT:
I want the records in the filterList which match the reportId  in the VehicleList. How do I get using linq ?

Comment: Do you want to find an intersection of vehicleList and filterList

Comment: I want the records in the filterList which match the reportId  in the VehicleList.

Comment: pls try this  var Vehicles =
    from filterList in filterList
    join Vech in VehicleList on filterList.reportId equals Vech.reportId
    select new {  Name= Vech.Name, Colour = Vech.VehicleColor };

Comment: Getting this error: "The type arguments for method 'IEnumerable<TResult> System.Linq.Enumerable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>(this IEnumerable<TOuter>, IEnumerable<TInner>, Func<TOuter,TKey>, Func<TInner,TKey>, Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the query"

Comment: Is your `filterList` definition incomplete? Perhaps missing `ToListAsync()`?

Comment: It is complete and has toListAsync() as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear why you need to look at `VehicleReports` if both `vehicleList` and `VehicleFilters` contain `ReportId`.

It seems to me you could leave out `VehicleReports` and simply do:

```
var filterList = await (
    from filter in VehicleFilters
    join vehicle in vehicleList
        on filter.ReportId equals vehicle.ReportId
    select filter
);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3wgAV1) as an example.

Comment: I want the records in the filterList which match the reportId in the VehicleList.

Comment: @Lily Yea? How does my solution differ from your expectation? Check out the link in my updated answer